# PCA with one "known" component

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

(The title might not be very clear, any recommendation welcome)

I have a $1 + n$ dimensional dataset. The first dimension measures a specific concept I am interested in and the $n$ remaining dimensions measure "other stuff".

I would like to summarize the $n$ dimensions to 1-3 dimensions, ending up with 2-4 dimensions if I include the first, and ideally the dimensions I end up with should be uncorrelated.

In order to keep the resulting data easily interpretable, the first dimension should not be changed. However, the first dimension is highly correlated with some of the dimensions in the set of $n$ dimensions.

What can I do to achieve this?

---

I think the following approaches could (maybe potentially at least somewhat) work, but do not understand their pros/cons.

- Use PCA on the full $1+n$ dataset, but scale the first dimension way higher than the other $n$ to force the first component to be very close to the first dimension
- Use PCA only on the $n$ dimension, then use a linear model to find the effect of the first dimension, and take the residuals
- Use a linear model to find the effect of the first dimension on the remaining $n$ ones, then use PCA on the residuals

Comment: Would this wording of you task sound? There is a number of quantitative variables (features). You want to reduce all but one to a smaller number of constructs (linear combinations, presumanly principal components) orthogonal to each other, and _also_ orthogonal to that one fixed variable.

Comment: This is indeed a good summary.

Comment: The third option in our list is one sensible approach. The first is one is a cumbersome hack, the second one can be very suboptimal. The third is good and sound.

Comment: Your last (no. 3) approach feels right to me. Center all the variables, V0, V1, V2,... Regress each one on V0 and save residuals E1, E2,... These residuals all can be seen layed in the same subspace orthogonal to V0. Just do PCA of these E variables.

Comment: Approach no. 1 is also feasible, I think it will apprach no. 3 as V0 variance goes very high. For no. 2 - sorry I haven't given a thought to it.

Comment: Is option 3 still the best way to do this?